# Degree of roots of unity in the spectrum of an integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ integer matrix whose all eigenvalues are roots of unity. It is known that for $n=2$, the degrees of these roots can be $1,2,3,4$, or $6$.

What are the degrees for arbitary $n$? The Jordan decomposition reduces the question to the restrictions of the corresponding linear map to 
 invariant subspaces. Can the degrees of the roots of these restrictions be different from $1,2,3,4,6$ or eventually $12$?

Answer (score 4):

You can write down an $n\times n$ integer matrix whose characteristic polynomial is any specified monic polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$ (e.g., the companion matrix of the polynomial). So for example, if $n=p-1$ with $p$ prime, there is a matrix whose characteristic polynomial is the $p$ cyclotomic polynomial, so its eigenvalues are the primitive $p$'th roots of unity. Is that the sort of thing you want? In general, if you write $n$ as a sum of values of $\phi(d)$ for various $d$, you can get a matrix whose eigenvalues are the various primitive $d$'th roots of unity.

Comment: So in particular given n we can have d be $\Omega(n \log\log n)$?  Is it known which values of d greater than n are possible?  Gerhard "Is Inverting Totient Function Enough?" Paseman, 2018.08.24.

Comment: And if a primitive $k$th root of unity appears, then all the other primitive $k$th roots of unity also appear, so there are $\phi(k)$ eigenvalues accounted for. So the converse (to the extent that it is a converse) holds as well (that is, if  primitive $k(t)$th roots appear ($t$ an index), then $n$ is at least as large as the sum of the $\phi(k(t))$s).